# Como puedo seleccionar fecha mysql sin hora?

Tags: php, mysql, date

lo que estoy haciendo es insertar registros con un campo llamado "date" que es timestamp y tiene valor cuurent_timestamp para que agregue solo el valor de la fecha y hora del momento del la inserción, pero cuando yo quiero hacer un SELECT donde "date" sea igual a "Y-m-d" no puedo porque tambien tengo hora, y si quiero mostrar registros de una fecha determinada tengo horas tambien, intento con DATE_FORMAT pero mysql no interpreta bien la fecha parece porque no me devuelve nada ejemplo:

```
$fecha = '2020-05-04';
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT title, post, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d ') date FROM posts WHERE date = '$fecha'");
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $fecha.'<br>';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJMlc.jpg)

Comment: Obtienes algún error ejecutando esa consulta?

Comment: No es un error, lo que hace es no mostrar ningún registro, porque le estoy pidiendo a la consulta que me traiga solo los registros con la fecha de la variable $fecha, y como el select ya tiene DATE_FORMAT se supone que los dos son 'Y-m-d', asi me muestra si quiero ver todo: 2020-05-05
2020-05-05, pero cuando hago el WHERE no me trae nada en la consulta

Comment: Es que la consulta como tal es correcta y te debería devolver solo la parte date de tu columna, prueba sustituir el lugar de date format, solo date de esta manera: `select date(fecha) from tabla;`

Comment: Parece que te sobra un espacio en el `DATE_FORMAT` aquí `'%Y-%m-%d '` después de la d

Comment: Ya probé eso y lo mismo no me trae nada, la única solución fue hacer insert manual con curdate()